# Heroku works only with Refresh

Tags: java, heroku, neo4j

I am trying to develop a Neo4J Cloud Application on Heroku, using their Neo4j add-on. I'm still trying out several functionalities, so it's just a demo app but already I ran into a problem.

My application is built like this :
I have a homepage with a table showing all nodes connected to the reference node. On this homepage there is a link to add a random node.

There are two actions defined in my servlet, which do the following:

**Home.do**

```
request.setAttribute("testuser", "test");
DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
request.setAttribute("NodeBeans", da.getAllNodes()); 

request.setAttribute("pageheader", "header");
request.setAttribute("pagecontent", "home");
request.setAttribute("pagefooter", "footer");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/master.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Where the last three parameters are the filenames (without jsp) which are included in master.jsp, using .

**Addnode.do** does exactly the same except that it changes the value of testuser and before setting the NodeBeans attribute it does this:

```
da.createRandomNode();
```

Which basically creates a random node to the database.

Locally, it all works like a charm. When I push to Heroku, there is a problem.

When I open, it still opens to *"bla.herokuapps.com/home.do"*, which is good. It shows me the table of the nodes. When I click the link that adds a node, the URL is indeed changed to *"bla.herokuapp.com/addnode.do"* which should add a node, but it doesn't. The testuser attribute, which also changes with the *"addnode.do"* action, does however change. When I refresh the page when the url is set to *"bla.herokuapps.com/addnode.do"*, it does add a node, and show this new node in the table.

So the whole switching between pages works good. The only issue is that clicking the addnode link doesn't create a new node in the Neo4j database until you refresh the page.

**For reference:** I am using the neo4j-rest-graphdb for talking with the database. It's a remote client library for talking with the rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. After debugging with firebug, it appears the page was not reloaded at all. Just the cached page was shown again.

You have to turn off caching manually in your controller using the following three lines of code:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
```